# symfony validation: How to make the validation range dependent on the validation group?

Tags: symfony, validation

How to make the validation range dependent on the validation group?

For example:

We have a variable, that is assigned to three groups.

When we validate group A, the variable x should take a value between 0 until 10.
When we validate group B, the variable x should be blank.

How could we define these dependencies in the annotations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) are designed to solve such problems. In your case, you should just add validation constraint annotations and set up groups for each constraint.

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Range(min="0", max="10", groups={"groupA"})
 * @Assert\Blank(groups={"groupB"})
 * @Assert\Range(min="20", max="50", groups={"groupC"})
 */
private $value;
```